# Need to return data from a completion block that is called in the same method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I have a delegate class that needs to return data for certain methods. My problem is that some of the calls that I make to get that data are async (using completion blocks), so it's difficult to return from the method with the data in hand. Here is what I came up with:

```
- (NSArray *)contentsAtPath:(NSString *)path
{
    __block NSMutableArray *contentsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    __block BOOL blockProcessing = YES;

    SuccessBlock success = ^(MyResult *result)
    {            
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < result.count; i++)
        {
            MyItem *item = [result objectAtIndex:i];
            [contentsArray addObject:item];
        }

        blockProcessing = NO;
    };

    [self.dataManager itemsAtPath:path success:success failure:nil];

    while (blockProcessing) {
        // wait for block to complete
    }

    return contentsArray;
}
```

Is there any better way to achieve this without having the while loop?

Comment: No matter *how* you do it: Waiting in the main thread for some task to complete is generally bad, because it blocks the user interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Something like this might work:

```
- (NSArray *)contentsAtPath:(NSString *)path
{
    NSMutableArray *contentsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    SuccessBlock success = ^(MyResult *result)
    {
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < result.count; i++)
        {
            MyItem *item = [result objectAtIndex:i];
            [contentsArray addObject:item];
        }

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
    };

    [self.dataManager itemsAtPath:path success:success failure:nil];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    // If not ARC then
    // [sem release];

    return contentsArray;
}
```

Also note that regardless, `contentsArray` does not need the `__block` specifier (at least for the code here).

Comment: It "might" work, but the solution is suboptimal with too many pitfalls. I know, the OP is desperately searching for a solution using "synchronous" patterns. But I believe, providing a solution employing the preferred _asynchronous_ style, would probably be more helpful.

Comment: The question was how to adapt an asynchronous API into a synchronous call site. Sure, if he could re-write his whole app to use asynchronous call patterns it might be better, but in terms of what he asked, I've answered. There's not enough information here to even begin to know what an asynchronous style solution would look like, because we know nothing about the consumers of `-contentsAtPath:`.

Comment: I tried to make the question generic, but FWIW, I'm using [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.io/) and this is how the delegate works. So I think I'm stuck with this way of doing it. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Unrelated to the question but a word of warning about OSXFUSE/MacFUSE: I've played around with it a bunch, and the overhead of Objective-C can be quite noticeable. You may want to consider using the straight C API.